# jQuery Best Practises for HTML Element creation in a specific example

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a better way to write the following so that:

a) fewer variables are used that may causes name collisions?

b) the code is smaller and more maintainable, especially on the line beginning "var $safesurf = $( ' ')" onwards?

```
var $ratings = [
    {
        group:  'SS~~001',
        name:   'Profanity',
        levels: {
        'Subtle Innuendo':
            'Subtly Implied through the use of Slang',
        'Explicit Innuendo':
            'Explicitly implied through the use of Slang',
        'Technical Reference':
            'Dictionary, encyclopedic, news, technical references',
        'Non-Graphic-Artistic':
            'Limited non-sexual expletives used in a artistic fashion',
        'Graphic-Artistic':
            'Non-sexual expletives used in a artistic fashion',
        'Graphic':
            'Limited use of expletives and obscene gestures',
        'Detailed Graphic':
            'Casual use of expletives and obscene gestures',
        'Explicit Vulgarity':
            'Heavy use of vulgar language and obscene gestures',
        'Explicit and Crude':
            'Saturated with crude sexual references and gestures'
        }
    },
    {
        group:  'SS~~002',
        name:   'Heterosexual Themes',
        levels: {
        'Subtle Innuendo':
            'Subtly Implied through the use of metaphor'
        }
    }
]

var $safesurf = $( '<div></div> ')

jQuery.each($ratings, function($i, $rating){
    var $header = $( '<h3></h3>' )
        .append(
            $( '<a></a>' )
                .attr( 'href', '#' )
                .html( $rating.name )
        )

    var $select = $( '<select></select>' )
        .append(
            $( '<option></option' )
                .html( 'Does not contain this theme' )
        )

    var $level = 0;

    for (var $value in $rating.levels) {
        $level++;

        $title = $rating.levels[$value];

        $select.append(
            $( '<option></option>' )
                .attr({
                    title: $title,
                    value: $rating.group + ' ' + $level
                })
                .html($value)
                .tooltip()
        )
    }

    var $content = $( '<div></div>' )
        .append( $select )

    $safesurf.append( $header, $content )
})

$safesurf.accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    event:      'mouseover'
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the entire thing in your own custom jQuery extension to scope your variables and avoid conflicts.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.yourCustomFunctionNameGoesHere = function(arg1, arg2, youGetTheIdea) {

        // your code goes here

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: So if I declare a variable with a name like "jQuery" or "$" (not that I would, just an example) it would have an effect? But for a variable declared "var $i = 'toffee'" above this extension and then used inside this extension (i.e. "var $i = 'fudge'"), it wouldn't override the value used before the extension? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You'd get a conflict if you made a variable named jQuery or $. Libraries like Prototype.js use $, and thus there are ways to get around this.  For your variable name $i, it's scoped to the custom function, so it will not conflict with any other variable declared outside the scope of this function. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work